# Is it possible to edit a UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton property?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uibutton

Say, for example, I was wanting to edit the title for the highlighted state, is this possible?

I know it is possible with custom `UIButtons`, but is it possible to edit the properties of the `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton`?

If not, is it possible to create a custom button and still call a `UITableView` delegate method?
If so, how would one pass the `indexPath` from a custom button cell?

Cheers!

Comment: set tag as indexPath.row then you can fire action according row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom `UIButton` and assign it to the `accessoryView` property of your cell.
If you want to do sth. really custom for the highlighted state of cells you should consider subclassing `UITableViewCell` and override `setSelected:animated:`

Answer (score 1):

give your custom `button.tag=indexPath.row` and access row no. from button tag

ex:-

```
    UIButton *deleteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [deleteButton setFrame:CGRectMake(285, 5, 30, 30)];
    deleteButton.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;     
    UIImage *newImage12 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"x.png"];
    deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    [deleteButton setBackgroundImage:newImage12 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [deleteButton setBackgroundImage:newImage12 forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteRemindersMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:deleteButton];

-(void)deleteRemindersMethod:(UIButton *)sender
{
    int rowNO=sender.tag;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, you'll have to set your own button as the accessory view. There are several ways to get the indexPath and my preferred is to get the touch coordinates using `locationInView:` and then `indexPathForRowAtPoint:` to get the actual `indexPath` that you need:

```
CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

(code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399119/custom-uitableviewcell-button-action/7399197#7399197))