# Obj-C - Delete tableview row if button in custon tableview cell is tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a checkmark button inside of my custom tableview cell. When that button is tapped in my tableview, I want the row to delete.

Right now, my code below deletes the row if the cell itself is tapped, but not if the button inside the cell is tapped. How can I make it so that if the button inside the cell is tapped, the row deletes?

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (tableView == self.sidetableView) {

        NSMutableDictionary *nodeData = [[self.myFriendData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] mutableCopy];

        NSString *nid = [nodeData objectForKey:@"nid"];
        [nodeData setObject:nid forKey:@"nid"];

        [self.myFriendData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [DIOSNode nodeDelete:nodeData success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

            NSLog(@"node deleted!");
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"could not delete node!");
        }];


    }
```

**CustomTableViewCell.m**

```
-(void)accepted {

    NSString *friendAccepted = @"friendAccepted";
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:friendAccepted forKey:@"friendStatus"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}

-(void)alreadyAccepted {

    NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                            stringForKey:@"friendStatus"];
    NSString *accepted = savedValue;

    if (savedValue == NULL){


    } else {



        self.acceptFriend.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        [self.acceptFriend setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkedgreen.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    }
}


- (IBAction)acceptFriend:(id)sender {

    [self alreadyAccepted];
    [self accepted];

        [self.acceptFriend setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkedgreen.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I can give a general idea of how this can be achieved in one way.

Declare an Outlet of the button in the cell class

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *deleteButton;
```

Next in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` `datasource` assign the target to your button to a function within the `ViewController`. Also assign the `tag` to this button.

In the action of this function put in the code and logic for deleting the data from your model/datasource and reload the tableView.

Please refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399119/custom-uitableviewcell-button-action) to assign action to your button in the `ViewController`. Hope this helps.

**Code Snippet**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.myButton.tag = indexPath.row
    [cell.myButton addTarget:self 
             action:@selector(myAction) 
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: I understand the first part, but the second part is confusing me: '...assign the target to your button to a function within the viewcontroller - also assign the tag to this button'. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: try the updated answer if it doesn't I will update the answer with the code snippet to do this.

Comment: Please update code snippet - lol I'm totally turned around :/ ha ha sorry, and thank you!

Comment: 2 mins please I can't find it writing it down

Comment: Hey! I think I got it, but my issue now is that 'tableView' isn't found (e.g. this line    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; ) if I place it inside my action? I tried self.sidetableView instead, but it causes my app to crash with: -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'

Comment: take an outlet of the tableview in your VC and instead of tableView use that outlet name I think this would make the error go away please try and let me know

Comment: That's what I tried, and it threw me the error I mentioned above? Hence self.sidetableView (that's the outlet name).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158225/discussion-between-brittany-and-md-ibrahim-hassan).

Comment: sorry there is one more thing to it the indexpath the button just gives you the tag thats is the indexPath.row make an indexPath and pass it on

Comment: @Brittany please check if your `indexPath` is nil or not for this statement `@[indexPath]`

Answer (score 0):

I think one way can be to use `delegate` pattern to solve this problem.

First make a delegate in your `UITableViewCell` subclass.

```
@protocol CellCalssDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)deleteCellForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

@end

@interface MyCellSubclass: UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <CellCalssDelegate > delegate;

@end
```

Second add the IBAction from the button inside this cell from the storyboard.

```
-(IBAction) deleteButtonTapped: (UIButton *)button; {

             [self.delegate deleteCellForIndexPath: self.indexPath];

}
```

Then Make a property of `indexPath`  in your cell class

Then in the class(ViewController) where you are implementing the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` methods.

ViewContrller.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      ....  
      cell.delegate = self;

      cell.indexPath = indexPath;

     ...
     return cell;
}

//CellDelegate Method...
-(void) deleteCellForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath)indexPath; {

        //write your logic for deleting the cell

}
```